# JMeter - Multiple functions in parameters field of Preprocessor

Tags: testing, jmeter, jsr223

I have two methods and i want to access it in script, using args[] array
[image]

```
String uuid = args[0];
log.info("uuid: " + uuid);

String mpi = args[1];
log.info("mpi: " + mpi);
```

this is giving me array out of bound exception, so can i have it like this in parameters bar or can i have the functions in the script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The delimiter for parameters is <kbd>space</kbd> and not `,` so you need to write

```
${UUID()} ${...
```